# How to Improve 1-Mic 2-People Video Podcast Audio (with Audience)?

Tags: audio, zoom, podcasts, audience, zoom-h6

Everyone seems to have unique issues, and I was hoping for some advice.

I help out on a video podcast/show, with two people at a table, and currently record them with just a Zoom H6 on a stand pointed at them.

This creates some issues:

- Table noise (example at 11:30 in the video).
- Inconsistent audio quality:

  - Sometimes the sound is hollow.
  - Sometimes room noise gets picked up.

Example show:

1. How would I got about improving the audio while keeping it fast and simple to set up and take down?
2. We are also going to experiment with having a few people in audience and want to record their laughter. How should we go about this?

Our idea is to get:

- 2x [Monoprice Large Diaphragm Condenser Microphone](http://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=115&cp_id=11502&cs_id=1150201&p_id=600800&seq=1&format=2) ($70) on a stand in front of each speaker or
- 1x [Monoprice Lollipop-Style Large Diaphragm Condenser Microphone](http://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=115&cp_id=11502&cs_id=1150201&p_id=600850&seq=1&format=2) ($300) on the table between the two speakers

and connect it/them to the Zoom H6 while using the H6's internal microphone for the audience.

3. Which of the two would be better? Is there a better alternative?

I'm not opposed to spending a little cash on a good upgrade, I just want to make sure it's worth while.

Thank you so much for any input / thoughts.

Comment: I can only point out:

1. There seems to be minimal clipping on one of the channels in the beginning: 
2. The positional audio is unpleasant on headphones. The effect is stronger when you see the video focus change but the positional audio remaining the same. I would suggest keeping it mono for simplicity for the speakers or toning the positional down.
3. A shock mount might help the issue at 11:30 (not sure if that's chair rubbing against floor or body rubbing against chair leather).

Comment: Hey!  Yes, I've been meaning to output to mono.. annnnd clearly forgot. Thank you.

Comment: Also: I'd love a shock mount, but haven't seen a solution for that that makes sense for the zoom h6.    I think the issue at 11:30 is the feet moving on the chair. If they lift or kick the chair with their feet I always hear it. Another common annoying thing is the hands rubbing the table, or hitting it when they get excited.